# Saving Integer value into database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

How do I save an `Integer` type (not `int`) into Database?

Comment: Whats the issue? Autoboxing happens in Java so what different does it make?

Comment: @subirkumarsao Maybe the issue is with the null value?

Comment: Im new to database. Im using  'Integer' and 'Number' type. If I rmmber correctly, I'd have to specify the table column what is the type of data that it will hold, am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Using plain JDBC, I'd use the following:

```
 Integer myInteger = ...;
 PreparedStatement ps = ...;
 if (myInteger == null) {
     ps.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
 } else {
     ps.setInt(1, myInteger); // will be autounboxed
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just use `Integer` is OK.Or use `intValue()` to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int, int)

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your database system (mysql, postgre, ...), the integer type will or won't exist in your database. It is then better to use java Integer functions to make an Integer from your database value, which will probably be int or even bigint, depending on what's needed.

As I said in my comment, something like `Integer myinteger = new Integer(yourdatabasevalue)` should work fine.

Comment: Im using sqlite, as embedded database.

Comment: I don't know sqlite very well, but from what I can see of the docs, it only has the integer type. Then you can store it as Integer in sqlite and make an Integer in java like `Integer myinteger = new Integer(here you retrieve your value)` (don't really do the request in there though ^^ this is just an example)